# the type of namespace name 'OVRGrabbable' could not be found unity OVR asset c# unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, oculus

i have a quick question about a script in my game and it has been working fine until recently. The scripts job is to detect if the right trigger is pressed and clone a game object. the script is

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Chisel : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Transform chiselTransform;
    private OVRGrabbable OVRGrabbable;

    public OVRInput.Button button;
    public Object cement;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        OVRGrabbable = GetComponent<OVRGrabbable>();
        chiselTransform = GetComponent<Transform>();


    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (OVRGrabbable.isGrabbed && OVRInput.GetDown(button, OVRGrabbable.grabbedBy.GetController()))
        {
            //clone cement stuff TODO: add cement manager to delete unused cement
            Instantiate(cement, chiselTransform.position, chiselTransform.rotation);

        }
    }
}
```

Im not sure if this will help but im using some of the code here https://youtu.be/98gfkursxYI?t=470

Any help with this would be nice. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which namespace is the OVRGrabbable type in?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I'm not sure how else to express it. You're trying to use a type called `OVRGrabbable`. Every type in C# is in a namespace - which namespace are you expecting that type to be in? Do you have documentation that would say?

Comment: im honestly not sure anymore also i just want to add that all of this was working before and i had not touched that class. i don't know if this also helps anymore but the whole library is throwing errors including the classes which cause the errors in my code

Answer (score 0):

a script was missing apparently. so after i after re downloaded it was fixed

Comment: I suggest you either delete this question, or make both the question and answer a lot clearer. At the moment, this answer isn't going to help anyone. Just specifying *which* script you had to download again would be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

```
public OVRInput.Controller GetController()
{
    return m_controller;
}
```

Must be added to the OVRGrabber.cs